# Django prepopulated_fields removes stop words from slugs?

Tags: python, django, django-models, slug

I am trying to automatically generate slugs to use in URLs of a Django app.

So far I have achieved this using prepopulated_fields in admin.py.

However, slugs generated with prepopulated_fields do not include stop words (i.e., the string "I love to code" has slug "love-code").

Is there a way to automatically generate slugs that also include stop words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slug is generated on fronted using [prepopulate.js](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0a306f7da668e53af2516bfad759b52d6c650b69/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/prepopulate.js) function and does not have any configuration options, you could add your custom javascript instead

Or

forget about `preopopulated_fields` and instead override save method on Headword model and generate slug using [`slugify()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) something in a line of

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Headword(models.Model):
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.slug = slugify(self.headword, allow_unicode=True)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```